# How to delete spreadsheets from hotmail

Tags: office365, onedrive, hotmail

I have a hotmail account.  When I click on the 16 dot square in the top left, it presents me with a whole bunch of tools.  If I then click on excel, it opens excel and lists all the sheets I have previously created.  Some of them are noddy ones which I would like to discard but I can't find a delete button.  If I select a sheet, it just opens.

Do I have to use another application or come in through a different route to delete the excel sheets?